# How to make columns have the same height of headline and subtext?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

This is a common scenario I run into and I have yet to figure out a solution that doesn't involve JavaScript. So let's say I have something like

```
<table class="some-table">
    <tr>
         <td valign="top">
             <h3>Headline 1</h3>
             <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor</p>          </td>
         <td valign="top">
             <h3>Headline 2</h3>
             <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
         </td>
         <td valign="top">
             <h3>Headline 3, Maybe On 2 Lines</h3>
             <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
         </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

or

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
         <h3>Headline 1</h3>
         <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor</p>    
     </div>
     <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
         <h3>Headline 2</h3>
         <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
     </div>
     <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
          <h3>Headline 3, Maybe On 2 Lines</h3>
          <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
     </div>
</div>
```

and UI designers or other pixel-pushers are upset that the third headline wraps onto a second line and thus causes subtext (*"Ut enim ad minim veniam ..."*) to be misaligned vertically with the other subtexts. The solutions I've gone with in the past, each of which has its own problems, are

1. set a `min-height` on the `h3`
2. add a class called `make-height-of-tallest` to the `h3`s and use Javascript to set the `height` of those `h3`s whenever `window.resize` is called.

Another failed solution is to separate things into rows like

```
<table class="some-table">
    <tr>
         <td valign="top">
           <h3>Headline 1</h3>
         </td>
         <td valign="top">
           <h3>Headline 2</h3>
         </td>
         <td valign="top">
           <h3>Headline 3, Maybe On 2 Lines</h3>
         </td>          
    </tr>
    <tr>
         <td valign="top">                 
             <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor</p>          </td>
         <td valign="top">                 
             <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
         </td>
         <td valign="top">                 
             <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
         </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

but of course that doesn't allow things to stack correctly on mobile.

What the Hell is the solution to what must be a common problem among web developers?

Fiddle:

Comment: Why not using display:flex ??

Comment: Using CSS3 flexbox would be the perfect solution for this, Google or use this http://osvaldas.info/flexbox-based-responsive-equal-height-blocks-with-javascript-fallback for more information on this topic.